# Getting Mailbox doesn't exist for existent mailbox

Tags: imap, dovecot

I am facing a weird issue where a mailbox is being shown in the LIST command but when I select it, it says "Mailbox doesn't exist". I am also allowed to select the child folder.

```
x login <email> <pwd>
x OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT MULTIAPPEND URL-PARTIAL CATENATE UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS BINARY MOVE SNIPPET=FUZZY NOTIFY METADATA QUOTA] Logged in
x list "" "*"
* LIST (\HasChildren) "/" ABC
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "/" ABC/aaa
* LIST (\HasChildren \UnMarked) "/" Spam
* LIST (\HasChildren) "/" INBOX
* ... other mailboxes
x OK List completed (0.026 + 0.000 + 0.025 secs).
```

Selecting ABC mailbox gives mailbox doesn't exist, but not for it's child folder:

```
x SELECT "ABC"
x NO Mailbox doesn't exist: ABC (0.006 + 0.000 + 0.005 secs).

x SELECT "ABC/aaa"
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft)
* OK [PERMANEN....
```

Selecting Spam or INBOX or any other folder works:

```
x SELECT "Spam"
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Delete

x SELECT "INBOX"
* OK [CLOSED] Previous mailbox closed.
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft $Forwarded $cl_1 $cl_2)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAG...
```

Can someone help me to understand what is happening?

Comment: It looks like it might be a folder than only exists to have children.  Nornally these are annotated \NoSelect though.  Can you access it with any other client?

Comment: I can't see "ABC" or "ABC/aaa" folder from OpenXchange client

Comment: As suggested [here](https://www.imapwiki.org/ClientImplementation/MailboxList#preview), it is better to use `%` instead of `*`: `LIST "" %` . Can you try this?

Answer (score 0):

As shown on [imapwiki.org](https://www.imapwiki.org/ClientImplementation/MailboxList#preview), you should avoid using the * wildcard, so you should use `1 LIST "" %` instead of `1 LIST "" *`
As well as this, `LIST` is a loosely defined command, and will often produce duplicates when using `1 LIST "" *`. Using `1 LIST "" %` fixes this issue.